# Alfresco: How often is the scripts folder refreshed? I've added a script but it is not visible as an option when creating a Rule

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

In Alfresco Explorer I have uploaded a Javascript file to `Data Dictionary/Scripts/My Company/my-script.js`. I want to create a rule that executes this script in Alfresco Share. But when I try to create the rule, `my-script.js` is not visible in the Perform Action > Execute Script dropdown.

How long do I have to wait before my script is visible in the dropdown?

**Update**

When I click on View Details in Alfresco Explorer, there is no Content Type property. I can see the other scripts have this. (Unfortunately I am unable to upload a screenshot.)

In Node Browser I do see this value for the content property:

```
contentUrl=store://2014/11/20/9/18/9c789a43-12c9-4df0-b9ba-8fd0eeb4ee1f.bin|mimetype=application/x-javascript|size=2925|encoding=UTF-8|locale=en_US_
```

**Update 2**
As noted in my comment, I am unable to see and edit the 'Encoding' or 'Content Type' properties.

I have checked that when adding a `.js` file to the Scripts folder, the Add Content Dialog has a section called General Properties and it shows: name, type, encoding and content type. (With UTF-8 and Java Script as the properties of the last two properties.) But when editing the properties after creating, these last two properties are not shown.

Comment: as you're using Alfresco, go to your script detail page, and click on "Modify" button (the one on the right of the Properties section) that will allow you to change to Content Type of your script to JavaScript. That should do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. When I click on Modify it takes me to a screen with the title "Modify Content Properties" and I am only able to see and edit the following: name, title, description, author, auto version.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to wait, double check if your mimetype is correctly set to JavaScript so that it will be picked up.

--- Update ---
I just looked it up and this should be the mimetype:

```
<mimetype mimetype="application/x-javascript" text="true" display="Java Script">
   <extension>js</extension>
</mimetype>
```

Comment: I have updated my question in response to your answer. The mimetype is correct when I look in Node Browser (see what I pasted in my question), but it is not something I can see or edit in the View Details / Modify Properties screens.

Comment: I can see the XML you have pasted does exist in the following file: `ALFRESCO_HOME/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/mimetype/mimetype-map.xml`

Comment: You should, try the Share interface anyway. The Alfresco Explorer interface is not maintained and in 5.0 it's totally gone :). So let me know if that helps. If not, then you can set the mimetype via JavaScript. Take a look at the JavaScript API how to modify content properties.